# How to do a bulk update to a Mongo DB array of objects with json matched by id

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, document-oriented-db

I need to update the MongoDB field with the array of objects which has id needs to be updated with same id in the JSON object

if I have some thing like this in MongoDB

```
{
    _id: "adqeer32423twefds",
    books : [
        {
          id : 111,
          name: "ABC"
        },
        {
          id : 123,
          name: "ABCD"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have the JSON data like this to be inserted in Mongo

```
{
    _id: "adqeer32423twefds",
    books : [
        {
          id : 111,
          author: "ccc"
        },
        {
          id : 123,
          author: "dddd"
        }
    ]
}
```

After update I need the final data like this in Mongo collection

```
{
    _id: "adqeer32423twefds",
    books : [
        {
          id : 111,
          name: "ABC",
          author: "ccc"
        },
        {
          id : 123,
          name: "ABCD",
          author: "dddd"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [positional update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to do it one by one, and batch those updates using [`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/).

```js
const data = [
  { _id: 'id1', books: [{ id: 'id1_1', author: 'author1_1' }, /* ... */] },
  /* ... */
];

const bulk = [];
for (const { _id, books } of data) {
  for (const { id, author } of books) {
    bulk.push({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id, 'books.id': id },
        update: { $set: { 'books.$.author': author } }
      }
    });
  }
}

// Check if bulk is not empty - it will throw otherwise.
if (bulk.length > 0) db.collection.bulkWrite(bulk);
```